# Installation of Opshub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility hangs after entering Verification Code

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I got the Verification Code and I am able to enter it in the textbox. I can also press the Next button once, but nothing happens after that. The screen just hangs, I can not press any of the buttons. I tried several times, even let it try the entire night, but nothing happens..

On the previous screen I had problems with my proxy, but after setting the _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable it seemed to work.

I am running the latest version (OVSMU-V1.1.0.005.exe) on Windows 8.1

Any ideas how I can continue?

Comment: Hi, this is an known issue for machines behind proxy. Our next release (which will be around Mid-April) has the fix.

Comment: Ok, then I will try again in a couple of weeks..